# Run InDesign ExtendedScript from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe-indesign

Is possible to run InDesign jsx scripts from node and pass in a callback to be executed upon completion?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this module if run in osx

[nbqx/fakestk: CUI Adobe ExtendScript runner. Accept script file or stdin. currently osx only"](https://github.com/nbqx/fakestk)

Comment: Do you know what target text in the jsx script fakestk expects to detect the correct Adobe application?  #target "indesign-8.0" doesn't work.  Thanks.

Comment: i dont have v8.0, but `#target "indesign-9.0"` works for me. also `#target "indesign 9.0"`, `#target indesign 9.0` works too. and `#target indesign9.0` return `Error: Application Unknown`.  what method did you used? script contents? script file?

Comment: Script file. It appears the begining part of my script file was dropped when read.  I modified the fakestk source and hard-coded the correct Adobe application version for now.  Working great.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess your script file is saved with BOM. I reproduced the issue by creating same script file with BOM and without BOM.